# How to compute a poisson regression zero truncated and one inflated

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, one-inflation

I'm working with data of trips per tour, with tours as various trips that a person makes consecutively. I'm trying to model this with count models. My dependent variable is Number of trips per tour, and the independent variables are characteristics of the person who is making de tour (Age, Sex, etc.), or characteristics of the tour itself (% in car, % in public transport, etc). I'm working on R and using the VGAM package.

I wanted to model this situation using Poisson and Negative Binomial, and since the data doesnt contain 0 (there is no tours with 0 trips), i used both models zero truncated. I used

```
vglm( y ~ x1 + x2 + ..., family = pospoisson(), data = DB)
vglm( y ~ x1 + x2 + ..., family = posnegbinomial, data = DB)
```

That didn't work very well. Poisson ZT sends some warnings about Hauck-Donner effect for a variable, and when I deleted that one, the error appeared for the Intercept. In the case of Negative Binomial ZT, it never stops running, and when i forced the stop, the last message was
`solution near the boundary; either there is no need to fit a positive NBD or the distribution is centred on the value 1`.

As I see, I have a lot of ones, and when i did a histogram it was pretty obvious, so I need not only a Poisson and a Negative Binomial truncated at 0, but I also need to take in count the effect that data is inflated in 1.

Making a research on internet i didn't find anything direct that could help me to do that, like the VGAM package, so i'm asking for help. If you know a way to do this with a pair of codelines would be amazing, but i don't know if i'm asking too much. Anyway, any help would help.

Even some clarification would help, of the warnings that I present (Hauck-Donner effect), does them affect only the significance of the variable that the warning is for, or of other variables too? And same question for the effect (beta). Tysm.

Comment: There is the pre-programmed `VGAMdata::oipospoisson` distribution that should do what you want it to (though at some point you should also consider having a bit of mercy on your data).

Comment: @PBulls thank you! i'll try this one. As I see, the package doesn't include any similar for negbinomial, right? And what do you mean with have mercy on my data? you lost me there

Comment: No, I didn't immediately see a negative binomial equivalent - a likely reason being that such models are really quite uncommon. By my other remark I meant that if you torture your data long enough & with sufficiently advanced tools you can get it to confess almost anything ;-)